# mkdir not working on a php inside a folder

Tags: php

I have a file into /js-calls/file.php.

it has this code:

```
$target_dir = "/img-posts/c_folder";
if(!file_exists($target_dir)){
    mkdir($target_dir);
}
```

I already have this /img-posts folder.
but c_folder is never created.
any ideas why?

Comment: could well be a permission issue

Comment: Is your error reporting level set such that warnings/notices will be reported? That may help you diagnose this. "Permission denied" is only a warning, for example.